# Need help writing a inner nested join

Tags: sql-server

Overview:  Write a sql query in the TestDB database that returns JobOrder records.

Tables Involved:

Since you are not yet familiar with the data schema, I am going to detail the tables that you will use in the query which are JobOrder, EntRequirement and Offer.

Query Requirements:

Select all JobOrders (only return the columns in the JobOrder table) with confirmed 
Offers whose FromDateTime is in the future. Confirmed Offers have an OfferStatusId of 9.

*Hint: The is no direct relationship to JobOrders from Offer.  You will need
to utilize the relationship between the three tables:  JobOrder, EntRequirement,
and Offer.

```
Select * from JobOrder where FromDateTime > today
and offerStatusId =9
```

- EntRequirement has JobOrderId as foreign key
- Offer has EnterpriseRequirementId as foreign key

This is what I have so far:

```
Select * from EntRequirement
inner join Offer
on EntRequirement.EntRequirementId = Offer.EnterpriseRequirementId 
and Offer.OfferStatusId = 9 
and Offer.FromDateTime > GETDATE ()
```

Please help with this.

Comment: This looks like homework.

Comment: Well, we're not going to do your homework for you, but the hint you were given should help.  You're going to need to include `JobOrder` in your query, joining it to `EntRequirement`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the PK of the JobOrders table is a column named id

```
select *
from JobOrders jo
where exists (
    select 1 from EntRequirement er
    join Offer o on er.EntRequirementId = o.EnterpriseRequirementId 
    where er.JobOrderId = jo.id
) 
 and jo.FromDateTime >  GETDATE ()
 and jo.offerStatusId =9
```